# Calculate if Hour has at least half double coverage

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have the following data that represets the hour and quarter hour with how many employees are scheduled to work.

```
Hour                QuarterHour         EmployeesWorking
13:00:00.0000000    13:00:00.0000000    2
13:00:00.0000000    13:15:00.0000000    1
13:00:00.0000000    13:30:00.0000000    1
13:00:00.0000000    13:45:00.0000000    1
14:00:00.0000000    14:00:00.0000000    5
14:00:00.0000000    14:15:00.0000000    1
14:00:00.0000000    14:30:00.0000000    2
14:00:00.0000000    14:45:00.0000000    1
```

I need to be able to pull the maximum about of employees Working, but only where that coverage is in at least two of the quarters.  So in my data above, I would return 1 for the 13:00 hour and 2 for the 14:00 hour.

Any idea of a good way to do this?  I have been trying to go a bunch of different calculations (Max, Sum(EmployeesWorking)/2, etc), they get me close, but I need exact counts.

Thanks

Comment: How do you calculate maximum? for 13:00 I would give 2 (very first record in the table gives you 2), and for 14:00 I would give 5 (14:00 record has 5 working)

Comment: @trailmax - `but only where that coverage is in at least two of the quarters`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always going to be picking the 2nd item if you order by the count within the hour, so do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY Hour ORDER BY EmployeesWorking DESC) AS RowNum, *
    FROM Table
) AS Agg
WHERE RowNum = 2
```

Comment: It's *always* the second value when the values are ordered descending... `5,2,1,1` => `2` *(In the OPs example.)* And `4,4,3,2` => `4` *(Following the OPs english logic.)* No need to check for `COUNT() = 2`. ***[Now, you just need to show the OP how to do that ;)]***

Comment: @Dems true, I guess it could be simplified further, creating a fiddle now

Comment: Psst - you've dropped this -> `desc`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I always forget my order by specifiers :) Thanks....and SqlFiddle is having some issues today, so just the query will have to do I guess

Comment: For some reason, focusing on the seond row for me seemed wrong, but I guess I was just trying to over complicate my life, cause both answers work perfect!  which I could award the answer to both!

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple - you want the maximum value from each hour, discarding one highest value. That sounds like [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) 2 to me:

```
;with OrderedWork as (
    select [Hour],EmployeesWorking,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [HOUR] ORDER BY EmployeesWorking desc) as rn
    from @schedule
)
select * from OrderedWork where rn=2
```

Result:

```
Hour             EmployeesWorking rn
---------------- ---------------- --------------------
13:00:00.0000000 1                2
14:00:00.0000000 2                2
```

If there were, for instance, two `5`s in the `14:00` hour, then the result for that hour would be `5` - because *one* of those rows would come second (but which one is unknown).

Note, a different windowing function (such as `RANK`) wouldn't be appropriate, because you *don't* want to merge tied results together.

---

Data setup:

```
declare @schedule table ([Hour] time,QuarterHour time,EmployeesWorking int)
insert into @schedule ([Hour], QuarterHour, EmployeesWorking) values
('13:00:00.0000000','13:00:00.0000000',2),
('13:00:00.0000000','13:15:00.0000000',1),
('13:00:00.0000000','13:30:00.0000000',1),
('13:00:00.0000000','13:45:00.0000000',1),
('14:00:00.0000000','14:00:00.0000000',5),
('14:00:00.0000000','14:15:00.0000000',1),
('14:00:00.0000000','14:30:00.0000000',2),
('14:00:00.0000000','14:45:00.0000000',1)
```